# Debuggers for C++

Tags: c++, debugging

Can anyone tell me what are the debugger(s) available for the C++ language.
Also please provide details about those debugger or reference to get details for the same.

Comment: Its just a google search man ! do it

Comment: I did that...i got crash, gdb, kdb, dbx debuggers. I was getting these in different links, But is there any collborative reference available, i means to say at once place are these detailed listed out ?

Comment: The wikipedia link I posted is about as close to that as you'll get I think.

Comment: I can advise you list debuggers for search memory leaks:
1 Purify
2 Bounds Checker
3 Coverity 
4 Glow Code
5 dmalloc
6 ccmalloc
7 NJAMD
8 YAMD
9 Valgrind
10 mpatrol
11 Insure++
12 Deleaker
I'm prefer the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger#List_of_debuggers) has a comprehensive list of debuggers. Far bigger than any indidivudal is going to rattle out off the top of their head. Of course without limiting it to a platform the list is huge and potentially full of esoteric solutions. For what it's worth most debuggers that started life with C also offer C++ support these days.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the two *major* ones would be the one built into Visual Studio and `gdb` for `gcc` although there is, of course, a plethora of such things.

It probably depends quite a bit on what environment you're using as to which debugger is suitable. Since you haven't specified even the platform you're developing on, that's about as much help as I can give.

Comment: I couldn't live without valgrind as well.